# Blender and 3dsmax Scale conversion

Tags: transforms, scale, units

At my work we use 3dsMax and are trying to transition to using Blender. One thing we've run into is that when we import a Blender model as an fbx, the scale is 100 times the size in 3dsMax, but the dimensions are correct. 3dsMax Local Scale is 100 times larger than it should be but the dimensions of the object are correct. In Blender the opposite is true. Where the Scale is 100 times smaller.01 and the dimensions are correct. I can apply the transform in Blender or the Xform in 3dsMax to correct the scale, but we want to prevent it from happening in the first place.

Other potentially info is that in 3dsmax our system units are in Centimeters. 3dsMax's "Local Scales should say 100.0 instead of 10000.0 and Blender's Scale should say 1.000.

I understand it is not optimal to be working between programs, but we need to be able to work between both fluidly so we can transition to Blender completely.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many import/export options include a scale to use when importing/exporting.

When exporting to fbx from blender set the scale to 0.01

When importing into blender go the opposite way, set it to 100.0

[image: scale import/export option]

Another option is to change [the units scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/scene/properties.html#units) in blender to change the sizes shown in blender. If you set this and [save the startup scene](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/3dview/startup_scene.html), it will be set that way each time you start blender.

[image: UNit scale setting]